# Como serializar ou Deserializar um json com chaves em lowercase e valores em uppercase (newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, json.net, newtonsoft

Eu tenho o seguinte exemplo JSON string: :

```
{ 
   myproperty : 'Hello' 
}
```

Quando eu desserializá-lo ou serializá-lo, quero que fique assim:

```
{
    myproperty : 'HELLO'
}
```

Todos os valores em UpperCase e Todas as Chaves em LowerCase

Codigo :

deserialize :

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

serialize :

```
var strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
```

Comment: Você vai ter que criar uma customização pro serializador. Ele até trata a convenção de nomenclatura para as propriedades (as chaves, no caso), mas não lembro de ter alguma configuração para manipular os valores.

Comment: Para customizar as chaves eu já encontrei, agora realmente não encontro na doc algo para tornar todos os valores em uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de consultar esse post: [Post](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/custom-converters-in-json-net-case-study-1/)!

Montei o codigo da minha maneira, é preciso melhorar , mas vai resolver, inclusive pq manipulo dados para insert no firebird.

Aqui o codigo :

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject obj = (JObject)JObject.Load(reader);
            string jsonrpc = obj["jsonrpc"].ToString();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(obj["id"]);
            JArray array = (JArray)obj["result"]["lista"];
            var listaProps = typeof(Lista).GetProperties().ToList();
            foreach (JObject item in array)
            {
                foreach (var props in listaProps)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (item[props.Name].Type)
                        {
                            case JTokenType.String:
                                item[props.Name] = item[props.Name].ToString().ToUpper();
                                break;
                            case JTokenType.Null:
                                item[props.Name] = "'NULL'";
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }
            var pizzaJson = new JsonPizza();
            pizzaJson.id = id;
            pizzaJson.result = new Result();
            pizzaJson.result.lista = array.ToObject<Lista[]>();
            pizzaJson.result.qtd = array.Count();
            pizzaJson.jsonrpc = jsonrpc;
            return pizzaJson;
        }
```

Para DeserializeObject :

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPizza>(json, new PizzaPagedListConverter(typeof(JsonPizza)));
```

A Classe `PizzaPagedListConverter` :

```
internal class PizzaPagedListConverter : JsonConverter
```

Para deixar todos valores strings em UPPERCASE ao Serializar :

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

            if (t.Type == JTokenType.String)
            {
                t = t.ToString().ToUpper();
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o JsonPropertyAttribute pra isso, exemplo:

```
public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Referência: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Comment: Não é exatamente essa a dúvida do autor da pergunta.